# setState updates component one state late

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

In the following code , the name(or any other object /not only string) only gets updated in the component after 2nd change .In 3rd change , it gets the 2nd change value and so on i.e. state is one step behind .

state is one step behind

```
const [state,setState]=useState([]);

const onChange=(id)={
let vname="hello world";
const temp = state.map((item,i)=>{
if(i===id){
return vname;
}
return item;
});
setState(temp);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell with less than 1/3 of your whole scripts... Could you include the whole component in your snippet?

Comment: setState is actually an asynchronous operation. So you might face issues if you are trying to access the updated state just after the setState action. If you need to do any such operation, use the second argument of setState which takes in a callback that gets executed only after the state has been updated successfully.

Comment: Use codepen.....

Comment: @ChrisChen i have updated a bit .

Comment: @AnuradhaKumari i know but i have a component (say a textbox) that needs to be updated right after i change something in it . So this function is kind of an onChange for a component . I cannot render it late when the state update . i have to render it then only as soon as the user changes the text in the textbox( textbox is an example not the actual component)

Comment: For that, you can directly bind the `value` of that textbox to the `state`. Check if this works,

Comment: so basically the code should be something like `<input value={state} onChange={()=> onChange(id)} />` .

Comment: @AnuradhaKumari yes exactly . i am binding it already . Thats how i am doingit but it's one state behind always . Also value={state[id]}

Comment: Unrelated, but proper indentation makes code much easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

First, that code looks a bit incorrect:
the onChange event should get the event parsed to it.

try something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [reg, setReg] = useState(["dog", "cat", "monkey"]);
  const [pujab, setPujab] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="name">firstName:</label>
      <input
        name="name"
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={e => {
          const newFirstName = e.target.value;
          setName(newFirstName);
        }}
      />

      <div />

      <label htmlFor="play">ChangeList: </label>
      <input
        name="play"
        type="text"
        value={pujab}
        onChange={e => {
          const newPujab = e.target.value;
          setPujab(newPujab);
          console.log("iniitiitit");
          for (let i = 0; i < reg.length; i++) {
            if (reg[i] === e.target.value) {
              console.log("yessss");
              reg[i] = "welcome";
            }
          }
        }}
      />
      <p>Animal List: {reg.map(item => item + " ")}</p>
      <p>Changes: {name}</p>
      <p>Names: {pujab}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I have it on codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-hodgkin-7x9nn